# Python functions with default parameters show unexpected behaviour

Tags: python

The following python code:

```
def test_function(a = []):
    a.append('x')
    print(a)

test_function()
test_function()
```

prints:

```
['x']
['x', 'x']
```

It seems like the `a=[]` default assignment is only used once, after which `a` is treated as a property of the function unless it is reassigned when the function is called again (e.g `test_function(a=['hello'])`). The behaviour is shared between Python2.x and 3.x so I assume it is not perceived as a design flaw.

I'd like to know:

1. What is the mechanism for this behaviour?
2. What is the rationale behind this behaviour? (it seems confusing to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is an expression, which is [evaluated only once](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) at the moment the function is defined/compiled. It is probably stored somewhere in the function-object, so when this expression evaluates to a mutable object like a list, you get the effect you described. I don't know about the rational for this, but it is a feature of python.

```
In [11]: def f(x = [], y = 123):
    ...:     pass

In [12]: f.func_defaults
Out[12]: ([], 123)
```